# box add from vagrantcloud using vagrant 1.4.3

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to add vagrant box using vagrant 1.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS:

> Vagrant 1.4.3 user@machine:~$ vagrant box add
>   ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64

and I get:

> This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
>   available below.

Obviously the format of command is wrong but how can I get box:

https://vagrantcloud.com/ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64

from vagrant cloud?

Answer (score 4):

`vagrant box add "ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64"`

is your answer.

**edit:**
My previous answer was based on the latest Vagrant version.
In 1.4.3 you cannot add boxes in this way because it's not working with Vagrantcloud.
Instead you need to manually specify the box url like this:

`$ vagrant box add "ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64" https://vagrantcloud.com/ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64/version/7/provider/virtualbox.box --provider virtualbox`

You should get the following:

`Downloading box from URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64/version/7/provider/virtualbox.box
Extracting box...te: 1591k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:00:02)
Successfully added box 'ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64' with provider 'virtualbox'!`

Comment: As I wrote in question. This is the command which causes an error.

Comment: But you didn't quote the box name

Comment: Can you share the output of the command with quotes? You use relatively old vagrant and I'm not sure that in 1.4.3 vagrantcloud configured as default repository. In 1.6.3 it's working.

Comment: Its' exactly the same: 'vagrant box add "ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64"
This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
available below. Usage: vagrant box add <name> <url> [--provider provider] [-h]'

Comment: @MichaelS: How did you arrive at choosing `7` as a version in the URL?

Comment: @krlmlr in vagrantcloud website, every machine has a Version link on the right side of the page. You can also reach it by adding `/version` to the url. On that page you have the full URLs for the machines. I just used the latest machine, which is version 7.

Comment: @MichaelS: So you count the items in the list, starting from bottom = 1? (Because now the most recent version seems to be 8.)

Comment: @krlmlr didn't pick the latest one (8) because it seems like it has been revoked.

Comment: The URLs seem to have changed, e.g the latest version of ubuntu/trusty64 today is https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150909.1.0/.  I can't figure out where to get the .box file from this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually look up the URL of the box you want to add, and use that instead.

So, for example, say you want to add the box `puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet` from Vagrantcloud, you need to:

1. Go to https://vagrantcloud.com/puppetlabs/boxes/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet
2. Click on a version from the versions dropdown on the right hand side (eg, 1.0.0) to get to: https://vagrantcloud.com/puppetlabs/boxes/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet/versions/1
3. Copy and paste the URL of the box for the provider you want to use. For Virtualbox in this case, it is: https://vagrantcloud.com/puppetlabs/boxes/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet/versions/1/providers/virtualbox.box
4. Use the URL to add the box like this:

   `vagrant box add "puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet" https://vagrantcloud.com/puppetlabs/boxes/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet/versions/1/providers/virtualbox.box --provider virtualbox`

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a while.  The key was getting the most recent version of vagrant -- 1.7.4 at the time that I am writing this.  The download link that I used was:  https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

I am running Mac OS X 10.7.5 on a MacBook Pro.  To download ubuntu/trusty64 I went to the site https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utm_source=vagrantcloud.com&vagrantcloud=1 which listed the currently available boxes.  You can search for a box by description.  For example, entering 'debian' as a search term returns a list. 
I selected a box and followed the instructions on its page (in my case the page was https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64).  Here is a log of what I did next:

```
    $ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
    A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
    ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
    the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
    `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
    $ vagrant up --provider virtualbox
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
        default: Box Provider: virtualbox
        default: Box Version: >= 0
    ==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
        default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64
    ==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20150923.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
        default: Downloading:         https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150923.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
        default: Progress: 56% (Rate: 111k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:28:59)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answer to your question, but I used:
vagrant box add precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
and then just change ffuenf/debian-6.0.9-amd64 name to precise32 in config file (Vagrantfile). And it looks like it is running properly. Probably there is somewhere a box file for ffuenf, but I don't know that.